# SQL - How to have a Parameter with dynamic columns for XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have 4 columns (journeyId,journeydate,elementid,channelid) but I want to only include columns with value (journeyid is a must to have value) in the select for XML path. But instead of having the values in xml format I only got the column names as the result.

```
Declare @JourneyDate datetime='2019-01-22 12:15:36.380'
Declare @ElementID varchar(50)=''
Declare @ChannelID varchar(50)=''
Declare @JourneyID varchar(50)='58597F9C-C468-4E30-A481-3B21170F9E63'
Declare @Selects varchar(2000)='JourneyID'
Declare @Addstate xml
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

if @JourneyDate is not null
begin
set @Selects = @Selects + ',JourneyDate'
end 

if isnull(@ElementID,'')<>''
begin
set @Selects = @Selects + ',ElementID'
end 

if isnull(@ChannelID,'')<>''
begin
set @Selects = @Selects + ',ChannelID'
end 


set @Addstate=(Select @Selects
               FROM [tbl_Journey]
               where JourneyID= @JourneyID
               FOR XML PATH('root'))

select @Addstate


Result:
<root>JourneyID,JourneyDate</root>

But what I need is below results:
<root><JourneyID>58597F9C-C468-4E30-A481-3B21170F9E63</JourneyID><JourneyDate>2019-01-22T12:15:36.380</JourneyDate></root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate and execute dynamic statement. With your statement the value of `@Selects` variable is selected for every row in the table, not the columns values.

```
...
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N'
    SET @Addstate = (
            SELECT ' + @Selects + N' FROM [tbl_Journey] 
            WHERE JourneyID = @JourneyID
            FOR XML PATH(''root'')
    )
'
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@Addstate xml OUTPUT, @JourneyID varchar(50)', @Addstate OUTPUT, @JourneyID
SELECT @Addstate
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

The xml should be formed dynamically as below which would add the variable value to the xml

```
if @JourneyDate is not null
begin
set @Selects = @Selects + ','+CAST(@JourneyDate AS NVARCHAR(255))
end 

if isnull(@ElementID,'')<>''
begin
set @Selects = @Selects + ','+@ElementID
end 

if isnull(@ChannelID,'')<>''
begin
set @Selects = @Selects + ','+@ChannelID
end
```